# why does every negative eigenvalue of $A^2$ has even algebraic and geometric multiplicities?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $n \ge 2$ and $A \in M_n(R)$ .

why does every negative eigenvalue of
$A^2$ has even algebraic and geometric multiplicities?

Comment: @Crostul - Why?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that square symbol. Anyway... Where did you find this statement? I have never seen it before. What is your knowledge of linear algebra? Do you know that eigenvalues of $A^2$ are the squares of the eigenvalues of $A$?

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $v$ is an eigenvector of $A^2$ then $Av$ is also an eigenvector. Now $Av$ cannot be a multiple of $v$ since then the eigenvalue would be positive. In particular $A:W\rightarrow W$ is linear, where $W$ is the eigenspace of a negative eigenvalue of $A^2$. Further $A|W$ has no eigenvalue over $\mathbb{R}$ and so dim of $W$ is even. (Because every odd polynomial has a root.) Incidentally the same holds if $W$ is the generalised eigenspace, (again of a negative eigenvalue of $A^2$), so the algebraic multiplicities are also even.

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: You are making confusion with eigenvectors and eigenvalues.

Comment: @Crostul No, oh sorry I see it, Ill correct it.

Comment: I still don't understand the answer. Supposing $W$ were even-dimensional, why does this imply all eigenvalues of $A^2$ have even geometric multiplicity?

Comment: @user7530 Not all eigenvalues just the negative ones. And geometric multiplicity is defined to be the dimension of the eigenspace $W$.

Comment: It took me a bit to understand this - I think it would be clearer if you said that $W$ was the eigenspace of a negative eigenvalue of $A^2$ - right now it's ambiguous what it's an eigenspace of (and more easily interpreted as "negative eigenvalue of $A$").

Comment: @MiloBrandt Well, yes, thanks, you have a point, I edited. I dont understand why people find my answer so hard. All the statements are easy to verify.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Unfortunately that's not quite true: the argument is difficult to understand because there are missing assumptions and steps. For example, the second sentence seems to assume that $v$ has a negative real eigenvalue, which is never stated.